# Is there any way to map filenames being handled by rsync between local and remote?

Tags: rsync

I use rsync to copy photos from various smartphones into a central photo collection, but I keep photos in my central collection sorted into per-year directories. However, the phones all use a common DCIM directory for photos of all years. I'd like to tell rsync that ???_YYYY* files belong under the YYYY/ directory, but I don't see a clean way to do that?

Comment: I would do a `rsync` to the desired destination directory for each year in the source.

Comment: True, I could do the pattern in the source path, but then I will entirely miss any files that don't match one of the patterns. I would rather have my mapping script throw an error and alert me to the match failing.